# Can't Install enmap-level (Visual Studio Code - Windows 10)

Tags: node.js, npm

In my terminal, I am getting a lot of errors when installing enmap-level. I have already run `npm i -g --production windows-build-tools` in the admin powershell and I am still getting lots of errors when installing enmap-level. Here are the errors:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Ethan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Ethan\MultraFresh\node_modules\leveldown
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN multrafresh@1.0.0 No description

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! leveldown@3.0.2 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the leveldown@3.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "multrafresh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Gamerholic/MultraFresh.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Gamerholic/MultraFresh/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Gamerholic/MultraFresh#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "better-sqlite3": "^7.1.0",
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "enmap": "^5.3.1",
    "quick.db": "^7.1.1"
  }
}
```

If someone could help me, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

enmap-level is no longer supported in version 4 and onwards. Since you're using enmap 5, and better-sqlite3, enmap-level isn't useful to you anyways.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of Enmap)